# How to remove/add the colon in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to change the time depending on value in javascript
if it has colon, remove the colon and should be integer format
if it has no colon, add the colon in javascript

```js
function checkColon(str) {
  return str.replace(/:/g, '');

}
var t1 = "10:40"
var t2 = "01:40"
var t3 = "0240"
var t4 = "1250"
console.log(this.checkColon(t1), this.checkColon(t2), this.checkColon(t3), this.checkColon(t4));
```

Expected Output:

```
1040
0140
02:40
12:50
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Your numbers need to be strings so I wrapped them in `"`

Answer (score 2):

You could use replace by regex group for the case when string does not have colon

```
function checkColon(str) {
  if (str.includes(':')) {
    return str.replace(/:/g, '')
  } else {
    return str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1:$2')
  }
}
```

```js
function checkColon(str) {
  if (str.includes(':')) {
    return str.replace(/:/g, '')
  } else {
    return str.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})/g, '$1:$2')
  }
}

var t1 = '10:40'
var t2 = '01:40'
var t3 = '0240'
var t4 = '1250'

console.log(checkColon(t1), checkColon(t2), checkColon(t3), checkColon(t4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works for you

```js
function checkColon(str){
  if (str.indexOf(':') > -1) {
    return str.replace(/:/g,'');
  } else {
    return [str.slice(0, 2), ':', str.slice(2)].join('');
  }

}
var t1= '10:40';
var t2= '01:40';
var t3= '0240';
var t4= '1250';
console.log(checkColon(t1), checkColon(t2), checkColon(t3), checkColon(t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the usecase but try this

```js
const checkColon =  str => {
   if (str.includes(":")) return str.replace(/:/g, '');
   let arr = str.split(""); 
   arr.splice(2,0,":");
   return arr.join("");
};   

const t1 = "10:40";
const t2 = "01:40";
const t3 = "0240";
const t4 = "1250";
console.log(checkColon(t1), checkColon(t2), checkColon(t3), checkColon(t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using replacer method

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wpdjG5/1)

```js
function checkColon(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?<=\d\d)(:)?(?=\d\d)/g, (m, p) => p ? '' : ':');
}

var t1 = "10:40"
var t2 = "01:40"
var t3 = "0240"
var t4 = "1250"

console.log(this.checkColon(t1), this.checkColon(t2), this.checkColon(t3), this.checkColon(t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `checkColon` check if the string contains `:` if so , then replace it or else add it using `substr`

```js
function checkColon(str) {
  if (str.indexOf(':') !== -1) {
    return str.replace(/:/g, '');
  } else {
    return `${str.substr(0,1)}:${str.substr(2,str.length)}`
  }


}
var t1 = "10:40"
var t2 = "01:40"
var t3 = "0240"
var t4 = "1250"
console.log(this.checkColon(t1), this.checkColon(t2), this.checkColon(t3), this.checkColon(t4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with `includes` if colon is in string. Delete it with `replace` or add it to the with `substr` partetd string.

```js
function checkColon(str) {
  return (str.includes(':')) ? str.replace(/:/g, '') : str.substr(0,2) + ':' +  str.substr(2);

}
var t1 = "10:40"
var t2 = "01:40"
var t3 = "0240"
var t4 = "1250"
console.log(this.checkColon(t1), this.checkColon(t2), this.checkColon(t3), this.checkColon(t4));
```